# SLDS is throwing my 2 lightning components out of vertical alignment with an unnecessary label

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, css3

This tiny unused label is pushing my selector component down on the page, and now it's out of alignment with the Pagination buttons. I don't want a label for this selector - how can I remove it? .slds-form_horizontalDeprecated would work, but it's deprecated.

[image]

```
<div  class="slds-m-around_large">
    <lightning:select aura:id="rowsPerPageSelect" class="selectorWidth" value="20" onchange="{!c.rowsPerPageChange}">
        <option text="5" value="5"/>
        <option text="10" value="10"/>
        <option text="20" value="20"/>
        <option text="30" value="30"/>
    </lightning:select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the label-hidden variant:

```
<lightning:select variant="label-hidden" ...
```

This is true for most input elements; be sure to check the docs.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this didn't work, even though the doc says it should. I also tried label-inline, which could help, but it doesn't work either. 
        <lightning:select variant="label-hidden" aura:id="rowsPerPageSelect" class="selectorWidth" value="20" onchange="{!c.rowsPerPageChange}">

Comment: @RyanMcNeely Hmm. I guess you could just use a normal `<select>` element instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to  hide that label of lightning select
.THIS label {
 display:none
}